# Firefox Addon hosted on my domain doesn't automatically update

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Since we aren't ready to load our add-on to the app store we have decided to host it on our server.
When checking for updates manually the update is picked up and the correct version is installed.
According to what I have read Firefox should check for addons updates at least once a day. 
It has been 3 days and the add-on hasn't been updated yet but as mentioned above, it does when I manually check for updates.

Comment: In firefox, the automatic updates for this addon are set to default

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that behavior too, but I think it's because the browser checks if it's actually in use before checking for updates. I.e. if you just leave it open without using it, updates don't occur. The reason I suspect this is because I can see my users are getting my updates.

You might try using the browser for a day and see if it updates.

Comment: Isn't firefox checking for updates when the browser is loaded?

Comment: That would make sense, but what I'm saying is that I don't think that's the case. Maybe check with someone from Mozilla to know for sure.

Comment: I have posted the same question in the Mozilla forums. No response as of yet.